# How to hope something is going well?

Tags: word-choice, usage, nuances

I would like to hope that someone's small business is going well.

I know if someone's business is going well they can say:

「店は繁盛している」

but, how can I say "I hope your store is prosperous/I hope business is going well"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, just add 願う 'hope' or 祈る 'pray'.

> お店の繁盛を願っています/祈っています

Comment: Can 繁盛でありますように be used?

Comment: @Flaw That is ungrammatical. You can say 繁盛しますように.

Comment: The ungrammaticality is also reflected in English as using でありますように would mean "to be prosperity(noun)" as opposed to "to prosper(verb)". Is this a correct analysis? (I'm trying to understand why it's not grammatical)

Comment: @Flaw It is close to that, but parallel with English is not always reliable. Often, corresponding concepts belong to different categories (e.g., 好き: na-adjective vs. like: verb). 繁盛 is not a na-adjective, and is a suru-noun.